# Android studio error :"Unable to locate adb"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have problem with Android Studio 2.3.3. Project can not be created,I try almost everything,reinstall application etc. This problem appeared since my Windows is updated, I do not know why. [This is image of problem and messages from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC7Zr.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you are missing sdk tools.

Look at the bottom right window (***Event log***) of your Android studio. It prompts you to download SDK Tools.

[image]

Simply click the blue link **Install latest SDK Tools** will resolve your problem.

Comment: It does not work,of course I would do that.I tried to install just SDK too but something other is problem

Comment: @nozzart Then you can post your new problem here.